# Is there a shorthand for smaller than AND greater than, in C#?

Tags: c#, expression, shorthand

Is there a shorthand for this:

```
bool b = (x > 0) && (x < 5);
```

Something like:

```
bool b = 0 < x < 5;
```

In C#?

Comment: Nope; you'll just have to do `bool b = 0 < x && x < 5;`

Comment: Would writing an extension method help?

Comment: @Robben_Ford_Fan_boy Using an extension method is going to add more than 4 characters at the call site (and adding " && " only adds 4 characters).

Comment: Its the `shothand` actually. One more thing you can have in C# `Enumerable.Range(1,4).Contains(x)`

Comment: @Shaharyar I wouldn't recommend an O(N) solution to an O(1) problem...

Comment: @Shaharyar, x can be float

Comment: Agree with the `flaws` in this. I just meant to provide another way to achieve it. Its not the best way that's why I commented rather than the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Latest C# Allow this pattern:

```
    var counter = Random.Shared.Next(0,5);
    if (counter is > 0 and < 5)
    {
      //Do logic
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

Nope. But you can remove brackets:

```
bool b = 0 < x && x < 5
```

or play with math:

```
bool b = x*x < 5*x
```

Comment: Plus one: I love the second one. But, it might overflow the type (or wrap around for integral types which would be a disaster), so we both know that the first one is the only real *feasible* choice.

Comment: Sure, I wrote it just for fun. I always use first approach

Comment: @Bathsheba. I deleted my comment (because I had mistook the second option for a serious suggestion), but what I said was brackets make it clearer. That's true, I know how operator precedence works and brackets still just make it read better on the page.

Comment: Thanks. I use the brackets for readability. Also, if I use an inequality, I need to actually solve it to understand what it means, which is not very readable. Thanks. :)

Comment: @NathanCooper: Personally I find excess parentheses obfuscating and annoying. But I work on scientific libraries so am prepared to be part of the exception group as opposed to the normal group.

Comment: I agree to put excessive brackets in complicated situations, but that expression looks pretty short and standard. Not sure how is it possible to misread it

Comment: Arguing against myself here, note that `0 < x & x < 5` *would* behave very differently due to `&` and `&&` being very distant in the precedence table!

Comment: What kind of nanny state is C# trying to enforce? It's valid in C and C++.

Comment: Actually, it will works same as &&. According to MSDN: "Binary & operators are predefined for the integral types and bool. For integral types, & computes the logical bitwise AND of its operands. For bool operands, & computes the logical AND of its operands; that is, the result is true if and only if both its operands are true."

Answer (score -1):

A LINQ solution, not shorter but more readable:

```
bool b = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }.Contains(x);
```

Comment: That works for the example in OP's post, but the question is about a **general** shorthand notation for "Smaller than and greater than". How would you handle `bool b = (x > 212) && (x < 45872);`?

Comment: @LarsKristensen - then you can use something like `Enumerable.Range(212+1, 45872-212-1)`

Comment: Yes, but then it's not a shorthand version.